# How to limit # of files being downloaded using session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have been using a database implementation to limit only one download at a time on my server.  This is kind of error prone and has known issues, so I thought about trying to do it with the session variables instead.  Only problem is that I use the following command before i start sending the file so that the user can browse the site still while downloading:

```
session_write_close();
```

I want to check if a variable in the session exists, then if not add one, close session, then re-open the same session and delete the old variable that i added.  Is this possible?  Or is there an easier way to go about this?  Or should i just stick with db implementation.

Thanks

Comment: I did, i couldn't get it to work =/  Was having issues recovering the session

Comment: I should mention -- someone can start multiple downloads by clearing cookies between attempts. They'll lose the `PHPSESSID` cookie identifying their session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I could not find a stable Session solution, as it was causing corruption in the session, so I ended up just sticking with my database implementation for now.  Sorry this question will not help future searches :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['downloading']))
    die("You already have a download in progress.");

$_SESSION['downloading'] = 1;

session_write_close();

//send the file

?>
```